# A number puzzle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

There are two people, each has an integer which together multiply to $8$ or $16$,

> A: I don’t know what number you have,
>
> B: I don’t know what you have either
>
> A: I still don’t know what number you have,
>
> B: I still don’t know what number you have either
>
> A: I know what you have now,
>
> B: Oh mate, I still don’t know what you have

What’s the number that B has?

Comment: Please edit the title, since it is so vague as to be meaningless.

Comment: The title is vague.  You should use a more specific title so users better understand what your asking.

Comment: Please suggest a title

Comment: @Marc I have added my answer

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt please suggest a suitable title

Comment: @Théophile please suggest a suitable title

Comment: "A number puzzle" could be one candidate.  It explains that this is a puzzle concerning a number, which makes for a decent title.

Answer (score 6):

B has $4$.

The possible couples for $(A,B)$ are $(16,1),(1,16),(8,1),(1,8),(8,2),(2,8),(4,4),(4,2),(2,4)$.

First round you eliminate $(16,1)$ because $16$ is unique in A's side so he would have found.

Second one you remove $(1,16)$ and $(8,1)$ for the same reasons for B (taking into account the removed couples)

Then $(1,8)$ and $(8,2)$ for A

Then $(4,2)$ and $(2,8)$ for B

We're left with $(2,4)$ and $(4,4)$, B necessarily has $4$, A we dont know.

Comment: This is not quite correct, since the numbers might be negative as well.  So it is also possible that B has $-4$.